# Question about computing the product of the numbers in a list using recursion without copying the list

Tags: python, recursion

I am working on a problem which requires to compute the product of numbers in a list using recursion. (i.e for input `list` `[1,2,3,4]`, the output should be `24`)

I wrote the code below:

## multiply_recursive_no_copy

```
def multiply_recursive_no_copy(list):
    tempPos = 0;
    return list[tempPos]*multiply_recursive_no_copy([tempPos+1])
```

but I don't know how to update the tempPos value each time through the recursion. Can anyone help please?

As showing in the previous section :)

Comment: Your recursion doesn't have a termination condition.  And Python has a rather low limit for recursion depth.

Answer (score 0):

You can post code by preceding each line with 4 spaces as follows:

```
def multiply_recursive_no_copy(li, i):
    # protection from out of bounds errors
    if len(li) <= i:
        return 1
    return li[i]*multiply_recursive_no_copy(li,i+1)
```

In order to update the position in the list you need to pass it as an argument. If you're not allowed to do this you may alternatively:

```
def multiply_recursive_no_copy(li):
    # protection from empty lists
    if not li:
        return 1
    return li[0]*multiply_recursive_no_copy(li[1:])
```

This will do the same, but passes the remainder of the list in its recursive calls.

Hope that helps,

--K

**EDIT:** Syntax highlighting helped me remember: `list` is a built-in type and function for Python. *Do not use it as a variable name!*. Also I had a typo or two.

**EDIT2:** [@KellyBundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy) posted an [excellent example](https://tio.run/#%23K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSG3NKcksyCnMr4oNbm0qDizLDU@Lz8@Ob@gUiOvNDcptahY04pLAQigPAVbhcyS1CK4JFguLb8IKq@QmQdTCdEGAkWpJaVFMHEFLWLs5ELSZ8jFVVCUmVeigUdftKGOkY6xjkmspub//wA) using an iterator in the comments below; it is much better than either of my above solutions.

Comment: Is it possible to precede each line with 4 spaces with the only parameter list passed in?

Comment: The comment about spaces was meant to correct the formatting on the code in your original post which has since been edited. The code itself need only be spaced to allow for Python to properly interpret it.

Comment: Please don't recommend using `list` as a variable name. This is already the name of the class `list` in python, and shadowing that name is confusing and can have unintended consequences because names in python are dynamic, not scoped. I see that you've added a small discrete sentence at the end of your post saying "Do not use it as a variable name".... But you do, yourself, use it as a variable name in the code throughout your post. Please don't!

Comment: @Stef, good point, I had originally left it for OP to keep it clear, but you’re right that it’s dangerous and lazy to leave it like that since not everyone will read the edit. I’ve changed it now to `li` instead,

Comment: `list` is not a keyword. And the first solution doesn't work and the second is massively copying.

Comment: @KellyBundy, edited for clarity; I figured someone who was asking about recursion and lists wouldn't really care about the technical distinction between a keyword and a built-in within Python, and instead used 'keyword' in the colloquial sense for a reserved string not intended to be used as a user-defined symbol. The first example has been fixed, the second example isn't meant to be efficient; they are both meant to portray the use of recursion and lists in Python, the underlying question from OP. If you have clearer or more efficient examples I'd love to learn more too.

Comment: Maybe adjust the second one's name then, doesn't seem right to call it "no_copy" when you even have a quadratic amount of copying. I might use an [iterator](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSG3NKcksyCnMr4oNbm0qDizLDU@Lz8@Ob@gUiOvNDcptahY04pLAQigPAVbhcyS1CK4JFguLb8IKq@QmQdTCdEGAkWpJaVFMHEFLWLs5ELSZ8jFVVCUmVeigUdftKGOkY6xjkmspub//wA), but I'm not sure that's what they're after. Their question is weird, I'd like to see the original task specification they were given...

Comment: Given that we don’t know the original spec I don’t know that “no_copy” means what you think it does, although it is a fair assumption, and would rather keep the name of the function as it was originally posed so as not to confuse the original poster. The iterator solution is excellent, I’ll edit your link into my answer with credit to you.